# Entire array being reset when trying to set a single position

Tags: java, arrays, object

I have really straight forward code, I am hoping that my issue is that I have just been looking at it too long. I am testing some calculations to make sure I am doing it right before I throw in a huge list. All I want to do is create a new objects through a for loop and toss them in my constructed array.

Contents of public static void main(String args[]) in my Main class:

```
PositionHolder[] positions = new PositionHolder[8];
PositionHolder currPosition;

int currPos = 0;
for(int i = 0; i <= 7; i++){

        /* For Random Points */
        currPosition = new PositionHolder(i);
        System.out.println("Resetting " + i);
        positions[i] = currPosition;
        //positions[i].setxPos(100 * Math.random());                // these get set in the
        //positions[i].setyPos(100 * Math.random());                // PositionHolder constructor

        for(int k = i; k >= 0; k--){
            System.out.println(k + ": " + positions[k].getxPos() + ", " + positions[k].getyPos());
        }
}
```

Just for clarification, my PositionHolder class is as follows:

```
public class PositionHolder {
    private static double xPos;
    private static double yPos;
    private static int point;
    private static boolean visited;

    public PositionHolder(int pointNumber){
        setxPos(100 * Math.random());
        setyPos(-100 * Math.random());
        setPoint(pointNumber);
        setVisited(false);
    }  

    public double getxPos() {
        return xPos;
    }  

    public void setxPos(double xPos) {
        PositionHolder.xPos = xPos;
    }

    public double getyPos() {
        return yPos;
    }

    public void setyPos(double yPos) {
        PositionHolder.yPos = yPos;
    }

    public int getPoint() {
        return point;
    }

    public void setPoint(int point) {
        PositionHolder.point = point;
    }  

    public boolean isVisited() {
        return visited;
    }  

    public void setVisited(boolean visited) {
        PositionHolder.visited = visited;
    } 
}
```

The problem is that for some reason each time through the for loop override the previous PositionHolders I have put in my array. As a quick example, here is the first few lines of my system output from the System.println towards the end of the for loop:

```
Resetting 0
0: 60.697435147416186, -96.35236848097432
Resetting 1
1: 57.98340997157546, -52.56948459757237
0: 57.98340997157546, -52.56948459757237
Resetting 2
2: 45.75236962694197, -32.03840605394901
1: 45.75236962694197, -32.03840605394901
0: 45.75236962694197, -32.03840605394901
```

So where I want 0 to stay at 60.69743.... and 1 to stay at 57.98340.... they are all getting set to the same (most resent) value. I wish I could say it is more complex than that, but that is it. What is going on?

--- The Answer, given below by Logan Murphy, is correct ---
As a note, not only should you take a break from time to time to avoid silly mistakes from code you have looked at too much, but you REALLY shouldn't rely on eclipses "fix" solutions to make good code :P

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because you set your variables to be static (shared between instances of the class). They need to be non-static like so

```
public class PositionHolder {
    private double xPos;
    private double yPos;
    private int point;
    private boolean visited;

    public PositionHolder(int pointNumber){
        setxPos(100 * Math.random());
        setyPos(-100 * Math.random());
        setPoint(pointNumber);
        setVisited(false);
    }  

    public double getxPos() {
        return xPos;
    }  

    public void setxPos(double xPos) {
        this.xPos = xPos;
    }

    public double getyPos() {
        return yPos;
    }

    public void setyPos(double yPos) {
        this.yPos = yPos;
    }

    public int getPoint() {
        return point;
    }

    public void setPoint(int point) {
        this.point = point;
    }  

    public boolean isVisited() {
        return visited;
    }  

    public void setVisited(boolean visited) {
        this.visited = visited;
    } 
}
```

This way each instance of the class PositionHolder has its own variables (instance variables are globally declared variables that are non-static)

Comment: Haha see this is why I don't even mess with statics, and thus didn't even think about it. I was just making an example to test so I could use the functionality of the algorithms in my code. Stupid statics. Thanks, I will check this but it should be good.

Comment: What do you know, surprise surprise it works. This is why you can't look at code too long (and don't rely on eclipses quick "fixes")